# Аналог scanner'а из java в c#

Tags: java, c#

Добрый день

Начал изучать c# вчера. Пытался создать калькулятор площади треугольника, но наткнулся на то что не знаю есть ли в c# scanner. Прошу помощи, ибо в этом языке ничего толком не знаю. Заранее благодрю)

Comment: Какой функционал `Scanner` Вы хотите воспроизвести?

Comment: ...начните с чтения литературы

Comment: Хотел сделать примитивную программу для счета площади. Думал сканировать числа, а потом уже вычисления делать

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для ввода строк в консоли используйте метод [`ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) статического класса [`Console`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx) из пространства имен [`System`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system(v=vs.110).aspx)
Для преобразования строки в число используйте статические методы `xxx.Parse()`, имеющиеся у всех стандартных типов-значений: [`int.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx), [`double.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.double.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) и т.д.